# PHP Class : Are too many properties bad?

Tags: php

I have a class that has many `properties`. First part of the question is as stated before, is it bad to have too many bad `properties` of a class? If yes, what measures should I take to improve my code and performance of the code?

For example, I have a Person class:

```
class FamilyMember extends Base
{

    public
        $stateId, $familyId, $memberId,
        $firstName, $middleName ,$lastName, $dob, $birthPlace, $father, $mother, $maritalStatus, $spouse,
        $gender, $religion, $caste, $education, $trainings ,$disabilityStatus,
        $stayLocation, $employment, $annualIncome, $mobileAccess, $internetAccess;

}
```

Does it help me making them `private/protected`?

Next part of the question is: 
**In a real-world application, how do people handle these? Is it ideal to have such a cluster?**

Comment: You might wish to show more of your question and instead ask over at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . In short, however, this isn't terribly uncommon especially when using an ActiveRecord pattern.

Comment: @Victory is a class that has some wrapper methods like `save`, `prepareTableData`, `createEdiForm`, etc... It is used throughout the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Base` seems to be a following something similar to an `ActiveRecord` pattern (i.e. mapping database table rows to a PHP object) this isn't at all uncommon.  You can use `protected` or `private` and a `getter`/`setter` pattern to make your code a bit more future proof. e.g. for row versioning.

Comment: Will making `private/protected` excel the performance of retard?

Comment: Generally speaking, it probably won't affect performance at all, the compiler will optimize it for you in the trivial (common) cases.